Maximal zero-sum free sequences of $C_3^n$
I am working on the Davenport constant for groups, $D(G)$, which is the minimal number $d$ such that every sequence or multiset of $d$ elements of the group $G$ always contains some non-empty zero-sum subsequence.
For abelian groups, we know a lot of result and facts.  In particular, $D(C_3^n)=1+2n$ so that maximal zero-sum free sequences have length $2n$. For example, the sequence consisting of each vector $e_i$ twice. Do we know exactly the structure of all maximal zero-sum free sequences?
UPDATE (2024-09-05). As Salvo Tringali states (thank you!) in the answer to this question, Prof. Geroldinger shared the characterisation for $n=3$.
As a summary, a sequence $U$ of length 7 in $C_3^3$ is a minimal zero-sum sequence of maximal length over $C_3^3$ if and only if there exists a basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ of $C_3^3$ and $a_i, b_j \in [0,2]$ for $i \in [1,5]$ and $j \in [1,3]$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{5} a_i \equiv \sum_{j=1}^{3} b_j \equiv 1 (mod 3)$ such that
$U= e_1^2 * \prod_{i=1}^{2} (a_i e_1 + e_2) *  \prod_{j=1}^{3} (a_{2+j} e_1 + b_j e_2 + e_3)$.
If I am not wrong, a sequence is maximal zero-sum free sequence if and only if it is a subsequence of length 6 of some minimal zero-sum sequence of maximal length 7 (characterisation above). If this is true (otherwise, please correct me) and I have "some flexibility" of choice of elements (for example, I have 4 fixed elements and flexibility of choice between two elements for remaining two elements in $C_3^3$), can I always ensure that some combination makes it NOT maximal zero-sum free sequence? Does someone come up with some corollary about the form of maximal zero-sum free sequences? Thank you very much!!
PD: If you are curious about why am I asking this question, the idea is to prove that any sequence of 14 elements in $S_3^3$ gives some one-product subsequence. If we have 2 elements of same "type", with 8 types (odd/even, odd/even, odd/even), then the product of both elements is in $A_3^3 \cong C_3^3$, and if elements are distinct then the order of the product matters, getting distict elements. Thus, in many situations we can get 6 elements in $A_3^3$ taking products of these 14 elements, with some flexibility of choice (if we get $D(C_3^3)=7$, we are done).

$C_3^n$ is the product of $n$ copies of the cyclic group of order three?

@GerryMyerson Yes

You might compute the number of such $2n$-multisets (or sequences, which would give a larger number) for small values of $n$ and check whether it appears in OEIS.

@YCor A zero-sum sequence over an Abelian group G is commonly defined as an element of the free Abelian monoid over G such that etc. So, there is really no difference here between the nr of zero-sum sequences of length k over G and the nr of multisubsets of G with k elements (counted with repetition) that add up to 0.

@SalvoTringali I viewed $a,a,b$ and $a,b,a$ as equal multisets but distinct sequences if $a\neq b$. Of course if instead one uses "sequence" for "multiset", this is the same thing.

@YCor I just wanted to emphasize that, in additive combinatorics, zero-sum sequences (over Abelian groups) are always defined, AFAIK, as unordered sequences

Btw, shouldn't the definition of the Davenport constant in the OP read "[...] always contains a non-empty zero-sum sequence"?

I sent an email to Alfred Geroldinger with a link to this thread. Here is a summary of his reply (I'm posting with his permission):

The structure of minimal zero-sum sequences of maximal length over $C_3^n$ is unknown.
Lemma 4.2 in [Geroldinger and Schmid, J. Korean Math. Soc. 56 (2019), No. 4, 869-915. DOI: 10.4134/JKMS.j180467] gives the structure of minimal zero-sum  sequences of maximal length over Abelian groups of rank two.

UPDATE (2024-08-29). As I've just learned from Alfred Geroldinger, the structure of minimal zero-sum sequences of maximal length over $C_3^3$ is the subject of Lemma 5.4 in [Geroldinger, Grynkiewicz, and Schmid, J. Théorie Nombres Bordeaux 23 (2011), Nr. 1, 137-169. EuDML: https://eudml.org/doc/219687]. This answers a question by Mikel Martinez Puente in the comments on this post.

Thank you very much! I was trying with $n=3$ and it was already difficult to find some characterisation...

Do you know if there is at least some characterisation or properties that maximal zero-sum free sequences must satisfy for n=3? I will write him an email maybe regarding this "easy" case.

@MikelMartinezPuente I don't know, but Alfred Geroldinger will.
